# git diff between 2 revisions included

Tags: git, commit, revision, git-diff

I'm doing a :

```
git diff --diff-filter=AM --name-only 59ade6e..c1fc4d8
```

The 59ade6e hash is a commit where I added all my files (my first commit).

But when I execute my command it seems that it doesn't contain these added files. How can really include my hash revision to this diff ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `59ade6e` is your root commit, you are probably looking for this command:

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r 59ade6e
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `~1` notation:

```
git diff --diff-filter=AM --name-only 59ade6e~1..c1fc4d8
```

This will do the diff between the commit previous to `59ade6e` and `c1fc4d8`